# Como acessar, em PHP, valores passados como parâmetro utilizando jQuery.post()

Tags: php, jquery

Como acessar, individualmente, os valores da string `cores` e do array `filmes` em uma página PHP?

```
var filmes = ["Mad Max", "Assassin's Creed"];

var cores = "cor_um=Azul&cor_dois=Preto";

$.post("autosave.php", {'_cores': cores, '_filmes': filmes});
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a tag [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

```
$filmes = $_POST['_filmes'];
parse_str($_POST['cores'], $cores);
```

Para pegar cada valor dos arrays enviados, basta utilizar o `foreach`

```
foreach($filmes as $filme) {
    print_r($filme)
}
```

Recomendo você alterar o formato da sua variável cores para um array em vez de query string

Comment: Jeferson, como pego cada valor individualmente?

Comment: Como você esta passando eles em um array, você precisa percorrer este array usando `foreach`, vou editar com um exemplo

Comment: Se você enviar as cores como array, basta fazer a mesma coisa para a variável `$cores`

Comment: `"cores"` é uma `string` é serializada a partir de um formulário. Isto é só um exemplo MCV.

Comment: Adicione uma opção para vc transformar query string em array

Comment: Jeferson, se puder complementar sua resposta mostrando como faz...